# MQTT protocol limitations

Tags: web, embedded, arm, sensors, mqtt

1.can I use MQTT protocol for embedded systems with 8-bit / 16-bit arm processor and 32KB Flash
4KB RAM ?

2.In particular can I use CloudMQTT service for such low power and processor : 16-bit processor,32kb Flash, 4kb RAM? http://www.cloudmqtt.com/

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are implementations of MQTT available for the [Arduino](http://knolleary.net/arduino-client-for-mqtt/) amongst others, so yes it is certainly possible to implement on the sort of device you describe.

Once you have a client implementation, it should not matter which broker implementation you use, whether CloudMQTT or your own hosted instance of Mosquitto (for example).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that that is exactly what MQTT is designed for, however bear in mind that MQTT V3.1 is a layer over TCP/IP, so you will need a working TCP/IP stack to start with.

MQTT V1.2 does not need a TCP/IP stack and works on transports such as ZigBee, but that necessarily limits the reach (i.e not an Internet connectivity) and would presumably not then work with CloudMQTT.

Comment: Just to be clear, it is MQTT-SN v1.2 that does not require the TCP/IP stack. CloudMQTT does not support MQTT-SN.